# Comparision using data from database

Tags: android, database

I have 2 tables in database.1st table is "inc" and 2nd table is "rec".In 1st table i have the following fields:

```
id   item  price  qty  total  cat  group  recc  reccid
1    sddf  65      1    65    rer   dfd   true  1

In 2nd table:

id   date        increment    type
1    27/07/2012   6            daily.
```

So what i want is i am retrieving data from table1(in that no problem) and showing that in a listview using simplecursoradapter.In this list view  i have 5 textviews to show the data.In that 5th textview should be dynamic(i.e) if "recc" in table1 is true means i am retrieving data from 2nd table and based on the increment i am doing some calculation.But when i am retrieving data from table2 it is always taking the 1st entry data alone.Based on the table1 for the length of the rows it should get that increment value form table2.Please help me..Thanks in advance.

My code is as follows:

```
 Cursor c = db.getExpensetitle(intent.getStringExtra("grpsdbexp"));-------->This is from table1.
            startManagingCursor(c);    

             from = new String[] {db.KEY_DATE,db.KEY_DESC,db.KEY_INCOME,db.KEY_QUANTITY,db.KEY_ROWID};
             to = new int[] {R.id.text1 ,R.id.text3,R.id.text5,R.id.text7,R.id.text11};

                  SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
                          new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.columnviewexp, c, from, to)
{
    @Override
  public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
      String reurrence= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("recurrence"));   
      float total=Float.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("total"))); 
      TextView text1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
      TextView text3=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text3);
      TextView text5=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text5);
      TextView text7=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text7);
      TextView text9=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text9);
      TextView text11=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text11);

      TextView recccind=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.reccurind);    
      String text=null;      
      String recctotal=null;

      if(reurrence.equals("true"))
      {      
          Cursor c1=db.recctable();
          startManagingCursor(c1); ---------->This is from table 2.
          System.out.println("No="+c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("startdate")));
            String  dates=(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("startdate")));
            String  types=(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("recurrencetype")));
            int  recc=Integer.parseInt((c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("increment"))));
              c1.moveToNext();    
          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
          String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
          Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

             Date dt=null;
            try 
            {
                dt = sdf.parse(dates);
                cal.setTime(dt);
            } catch (ParseException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }             

            int daysInSameMonth=0;    ------------------>For getting this value only i am doing this..It gives always the first entry count.
            int count[]=new int[c1.getCount()];
            for(int j=1;j<recc;j++)
            {
                 int currentDay= cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                 int lastDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);     
                 System.out.println("b4 inc");
                 daysInSameMonth++;
                 if(types.equals("Daily"))
                 {                              
                  cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);    
                  Date dtNew=cal.getTime();
                  cal.setTime(dtNew);                        
                  if(currentDay==lastDay)
                     {  
                      System.out.println("count="+daysInSameMonth);

                       break;
                     }  
//                   System.out.println("days="+daysInSameMonth[i]);

                }
                 else if(types.equals("Weekly"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Inside week");
                    System.out.println("current="+currentDay);
                    System.out.println("last="+lastDay);
                    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
                     if(currentDay<=lastDay)
                     {               
                       break;
                     }  
                }          

            }       
            System.out.println("subbu="+daysInSameMonth);
            System.out.println("totttt="+daysInSameMonth*total);

             recctotal=String.valueOf(daysInSameMonth*total);
             text9.setText(recctotal);

      }

      else
      {       

          text9.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_TOTAL)));       
      }
```

Comment: add code for startManagingCursor method or class

Comment: Thanks Khan ..Please give more details..

Answer (score 0):

you should have to use either **for** loop or while for getting multiple row data from table as shown below

```
 if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()!=0){

  for(cursor.moveToFirst();!cursor.isAfterLast();cursor.moveToNext()){

 // Do here your stuff what you want 

  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks khan..But it will not meet my requirement..By your code It will give the last value